# if condition not responding as expected in django for a like button

Tags: python, html, django

I actually have a properly working like button for my post, but I wanted that to change to dislike if the user has already liked the post. but am unable to change the button using if condition.

view.py file

```
def home(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'posts': Post,
        'is_liked':is_liked,
            }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html',context)

def like_post(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.POST.get("post_id"))
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        is_liked = True
        post.likes.add(request.user.id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

html file:

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if is_liked %}
<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class= "btn btn-danger">Dislike</button> 
{% else %}
<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class= "btn btn-info">Like</button> 
{% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: What issue/error you facing/getting ?

Comment: change `{% is_liked %}` to `{{ is_liked }}` and print in console to check what you are getting as output.

Comment: i dont have any issue or error, even the like button works fine.... but the button which displays on the html page does not react as per if condition. i always see "Like" button only, but i expect to see dislike button when user already liked it

Comment: @shaikmoeed I don't see anything actually

Comment: So, that is the reason you are getting `button` in else block by default.

Comment: @shaikmoeed yeah, i noticed that. so how do i do that as i expected?

Comment: @nikhil your id in the filter references to the pk of post table in your database, I guess that is not what you want to compare, isn't it?

Comment: How are you accessing `request`? What I mean to say is, you need to do something like `request['is_liked']` as you return through request in `home` function.

Comment: @PriteshThaker i just wanted to see if the user who is logged in has like the post or not using the filter

Comment: @shaikmoeed I didn't exactly get what you want me to..... can you please elaborate?

Comment: According to your logic in view.py file, what you are doing is, when button is clicked,a post request has came and you modified and returned the request. But from frontend you are not doing any for that. The value is remained same as it is in last post request.

Comment: @shaikmoeed  yeah, so what change in the code can I do now? ..... I'm new to Django so don't mind.

Comment: Check my answer, I have updated values from front-end itself. Please check and confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To set custom tags, follow this steps:**

The most common place to specify custom template tags and filters is inside a Django app. If they relate to an existing app, it makes sense to bundle them there; otherwise, they can be added to a new app. When a Django app is added to INSTALLED_APPS, any tags it defines in the conventional location described below are automatically made available to load within templates.

The app should contain a `templatetags` directory, at the same level as `models.py, views.py, etc.` If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the `__init__.py` file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.

Create a `set_var.py` file.

**custom_set_tag.py:**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

class SetVarNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, var_name, var_value):
        self.var_name = var_name
        self.var_value = var_value

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            value = template.Variable(self.var_value).resolve(context)
        except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
            value = ""
        context[self.var_name] = value
        return u""

def set_var(parser, token):
    """
        {% set <var_name>  = <var_value> %}
    """
    parts = token.split_contents()
    if len(parts) < 4:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("'set' tag must be of the form:  {% set <var_name>  = <var_value> %}")
    return SetVarNode(parts[1], parts[3])

register.tag('set', set_var)
```

**Code:**

```
{% load set_var %}
{% set is_liked = 'liked' %}
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if is_liked == 'liked' %} // this line is modified.
<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class= "btn btn-danger">Dislike</button> 
{% set is_liked = 'dislike' %}
{% elif is_liked == 'dislike' %}
<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class= "btn btn-info">Like</button> 
{% set is_liked = 'liked' %}
{% endif %}
</form>
{% endwith %}
```

**Another way:**
Only to toggle between like and dislike,

**Add this in html:**

```
<!-- Use an element to toggle between a like/dislike icon -->
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
```

**Add this in script:**

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-thumbs-down");
}
```

Comment: @nikhilbodduluri Sorry, that is typo error present in my code. please check now.

Comment: error: 'set', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: wrapped in `with` and updated answer. please check and confirm

Comment: error: 'with' expected at least one variable assignment

Comment: i know you are trying really hard for me brother but i have an .... error : 'set', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Try to keep both set and with. Previously we have assigned with set. Actually set is working, we are not using properly. Or give me some time. I will test on my machine. But this method make your process easy. Normally you need sent post request from front end.

Comment: sure brother take your time

Comment: Try now. `set` is not allowed by django. So, I have created a custom tag for the same.

Comment: this is working now, thank you somuch for your time

Comment: @nikhil bodduluri You are welcome. Learned more from this question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the post request, you must save your changes made in the model (with .save() method). Also, you are not using is_liked variable:

```
def like_post(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.POST.get("post_id"))
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user.id)
        post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

Comment: ya I know I'm not using it, but I wanted to use it and show the difference within the button displaying in HTML

Comment: I don't understand you. The conditional is not working because you are not making changes in your models.

Comment: i have added this in my models: likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)

Comment: can you please try my solution and give me an answer about how it worked?

Comment: I have tried and there is no difference in the result, but thanks for your time